# What JavaMail implementation to use with open jdk 8

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Given the oracle jdk is paid now we are migrating to openjdk 8, can I still use com.sun.mail.javax.mail 1.6.2 jar in the production or whats the alternative for openjdk?

Comment: [JavaMail](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/) is open source (under the CDDL license).  It will be transferred to the Eclipse Foundation in the future.

Comment: @stdunbar It has already been transferred to the Eclipse Foundation. The repository (+ site) you linked is archived. The current one is at https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mail / https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/

Answer (score 5):

The JavaMail library is not tied to the Oracle JDK or JVM implementation, and was already open source. It is dual-licensed under the [Common Development and Distribution License (CDDL) v1.1 and GNU General Public License (GPL) v2 with Classpath Exception](https://oss.oracle.com/licenses/CDDL+GPL-1.1).

So the licensing changes of the Oracle JDK and JVM do not affect usage of JavaMail at all. You can continue to use it, irrespective of the JVM implementation you're using.

In addition, Oracle has transferred JavaMail to the Eclipse Foundation. The license has been changed to the [Eclipse Public License - v 2.0](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mail/blob/master/LICENSE.md), and it has been renamed to JakartaMail for the API, and Angus Mail for the (reference) implementation.

See for more information:

- https://jakartaee.github.io/mail-api/ - the JakartaMail API
- https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/angus-mail/ - Angus Mail (reference implementation of the JakartaMail API). This was previously JavaMail and for a short time JakartaMail.

Comment: http://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/ is not there. Crucial for JavaMail is managing SSL Providers.

Comment: @SamGinrich That's because the project moved around and changed its name a few times, and was split in the JakartaMail API and Angus Mail for the implementation.

Comment: @SamGinrich Replaced the link with links to the JakartaMail API project and the Angus Mail project.